# Word macros: is there an event that's fired when content (macros) is enabled?

Tags: vba, events, ms-word

When I open Word documents that contain macros, Word's default behavior is to post a **Security Warning** and present a button with the caption "`Enable Contents`."
My question is whether is a way to be notified (e.g. via an event) when the user clicks this Enable Content button.

I couldn't find anything like it in the [Word DOM reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841702.aspx).

Comment: Have you tried using a Document_open event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no event that's fired off.  You could have a thread that monitors the screen for that button and click it with API.  You could enable all macros so it doesn't appear.  See this article: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-HA010354316.aspx